# How to tracker screen time of a component in React Application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to track time for which a given component was rendered with given props and active screen in React. What is the best possible way to approach this problem ? I wasn't able to find any good library that would allow this.

- Start timer - When component mounts
- Pause timer - if user navigates to different screen or switches the tab or loses focus.
- Stop timer when the component is unmounted or on navigation.

Comment: Use react dev-tools? https://beta.reactjs.org/blog/2018/09/10/introducing-the-react-profiler#profiling-an-application

Comment: oho this is a feature not something for testing environment.

Answer (score 0):

I was researching this same thing and came across some solution.
I hope this helps:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

function MyComponent() {
   const startTimeRef = useRef(null); // useRef for storing start time
   const [totalTimeSpent, setTotalTimeSpent] = useState(0); // State for total time

   useEffect(() => {
      startTimeRef.current = Date.now(); // Capture start time when mounted
      return () => {
         // Cleanup function: Update total time and clear start time
         const endTime = Date.now();
         setTotalTimeSpent(prevTime => prevTime + (endTime - startTimeRef.current));
         startTimeRef.current = null;
      };
   }, []); // Empty dependency array: runs only on mount/unmount

   // ... rest of your component

   return (
      <div>
          {/* Your component content */}
          <p>Total time spent: {totalTimeSpent} ms</p>
      </div>
   );
}
```